# Jenkinsfile issue while running script with sh

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have the following Jenkinsfile

```
def ARTIFACTS_JOB_ID;
def ARTIFACTS_URL;

node('CentOs') {
    checkout scm
    stage('Example') {
        echo 'Download artifacts'
        sh 'curljson  --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: tdzis3" "https://gitlab-sample.com/api/v4/projects/63/jobs" > jobs.json'
        ARTIFACTS_JOB_ID = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'python GetID.py').trim()
        ARTIFACTS_URL = "https://gitlab-sample.com/api/v4/projects/63/jobs/${ARTIFACTS_JOB_ID}/artifacts"
        echo "======> $ARTIFACTS_URL"
        sh 'echo $ARTIFACTS_URL'
        sh 'curl --output artifacts.zip --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: tdzis3" "$ARTIFACTS_URL"'
    }
}
```

while trying to get the artifact, it's calling

`'curl --output artifacts.zip --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: tdzis3" ""'` with empty url

Similarly

```
echo "======> $ARTIFACTS_URL" //works fine
sh 'echo $ARTIFACTS_URL' // shows empty string, tried with ${ARTIFACTS_URL} aswell.
```

is there a way I can run it as below (so I don't have to use `sh`)

```
def ARTIFACTS_JOB_ID;
def ARTIFACTS_URL;

node('CentOs') {
    checkout scm
    stage('Example') {
        script {
            echo 'Download artifacts'
            curljson  --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: tdzis3" "https://gitlab-sample.com/api/v4/projects/63/jobs" > jobs.json
        }
    }
}
```

without `sh` I am getting invalid syntax error while doing 
`curljson  --header`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable declaration `ARTIFACTS_URL = "https://..."` is a Groovy global variable. Hence, it is not naturally available to the `sh` step as a shell variable.

You need to wrap the commands inside the `sh` step with double quotes instead of single quotes as `sh "echo $ARTIFACTS_URL"` for Groovy to interpolate it as a Groovy variable.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
sh "curl --output artifacts.zip --header 'PRIVATE-TOKEN: tdzis3' '{$ARTIFACTS_URL}'"
```

?

for multiple sh commands you could also use

```
sh """
curl command here
cd command next 
etc
"""
```